# How to install a custom GMP lib for just one user?

Tags: compiling, gcc, libraries

I'm doing some heavy number crunching on one system and I'd like to compile (and finetune) a custom GMP 6.1.0 for the user launching the number crunching computation. Previously I had a Debian wheezy (7.6) system on which I installed a custom GMP lib while being root and modificating things left and right in the filesystem (because I didn't know any better). It ended up working: my custom GMP lib was crunching numbers about 15% faster than the stock GMP.

Now I installed a new Debian (Jessie 8.3) on that computer with the "stock" GMP (the one that comes with Debian Jessie):

```
# gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2

# apt-get install libgmp10
# apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

Which is apparently GMP 6.0.0.

I'm compiling my number crunching program doing:

```
$ gcc crunch.c -o crunch.o -L/gmp_install/lib -lgmp
```

*(I know I could probably gain some by messing with some parameters passed to GCC, but the big problem here is the "slowness" of the non-custom GMP).*

I then invoke *./crunch.o* and it works but it is 15% slower than my custom build GMP on my old system (using the exact same gcc compilation command pasted above on the exact same computer).

I'd now like to compile a custom GMP 6.1.0 again, but only accessible for the user running the heavy computation.

In other words: I'd now like to install a custom GMP cleanly instead of messing (while being root) with the entire filesystem.

But I don't understand what *-L/gmp_install/lib* refers to nor what *-lgmp* does either.

I take it the first steps I need to do are:

- go to https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/
- download gmp-6.1.0.tar.bz2
- untar
- ???

So how can I compile a custom GMP for one (non root) user account and how would I go about then compiling my crunch.c program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following steps as normal user

```
tar xvjf gmp-6.1.0.tar.bz2
cd gmp-6.1.0
./configure --prefix=${HOME}/gmp/6.1.0
make 
make install
```

This will install gmp in `~/gmp/6.1.0`. Now if you want to use this version to compile software against or use it at runtime, you have to set some environment variables:

```
GMP_DIR="${HOME}/gmp/6.1.0"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${GMP_DIR}/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=${GMP_DIR}/lib64:$LIBRARY_PATH
export CPATH=${GMP_DIR}/include:$CPATH
```

You could put that into your `~/.bashrc` or in a separate file you `source` just before you want to use it, or write a wrapper script including your binary stuff. Other people like to use `environment-modules` for this kind of tasks.

The `-lgmp` argument tells your linker to link against the shared library `libgmp.so` and `-L/gmp_install/lib` means to search for libraries in `/gmp_install/lib` and in the well known paths (`/lib, lib64, /usr/lib, /usr/lib64, ...)`.

The environment variables are used as follows:

- `LIBRARY_PATH` should provide the same as the `-L` switch
- `CPATH` provides an additional search path for the header files
- `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is needed for the runtime

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. Btw is the LIBRARY_PATH export supposed to append LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have corrected it in the answer.